# calculate years and months, 2 fields, 2 different tables

Tags: php, date, datetime

Using the following query I am trying to figure out how to calculate the difference between two dates in two different fields.

The starting date is:   vlg.firstflight
The ending/older date is:  vg.vertrekdatum

I want to display it as:

```
echo "    <td width='100' bgcolor='$row_color'>".$row['ageYears'] . "en "       .$row['ageMonths'] ."</td>";
```

How can I do this to calculate the "age" in years and months...

I tried doing:
DATEDIFF(vlg.firstflight,vg.vertrekdatum) Age1     but this did not work ;-(

```
$sql = "SELECT vg.gegevenID, lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij, vg.vertrekdatum,
vg.vertrekdatum2, vg.vertrekluchthaven, vg.aankomstluchthaven, vg.toestel, 
vg.inschrijvingnmr, vlg.vliegtuignaam, vg.vluchtnmr, t.toestel AS toestelnaam,
lh.luchthavencode, lh.luchthavennaam, lh.countryflag, lh2.luchthavencode AS 
aankomstluchthavencode, lh2.countryflag AS countryflagaankomst, vlg.firstflight

FROM (tbl_vliegtuiggegevens vlg

INNER JOIN (tbl_luchtvaartmaatschappij lvm INNER JOIN tbl_vluchtgegevens vg ON
lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID = vg.luchtvaartmaatschappij) ON (vlg.inschrijvingnmr = 
vg.inschrijvingnmr) AND (vlg.lvmID = lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappijID)) INNER JOIN
 tbl_toestel t ON vg.toestel = t.toestelID

  left join tbl_luchthaven lh
on vg.vertrekluchthaven = lh.luchthavenID

  left join tbl_luchthaven lh2
 on vg.aankomstluchthaven = lh2.luchthavenID

GROUP BY  lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij, t.toestel, vg.inschrijvingnmr, vg.vertrekdatum2

ORDER BY lvm.luchtvaartmaatschappij, t.toestel, vg.vertrekdatum2 DESC,     vg.inschrijvingnmr";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get the difference in days between the two dates.  Then you could take that number and further divide by days in a year to get number of years.  Using the modulus operator to get the remainder

```
$difference = ((strtotime($firstDate) - strtotime($secondDate)) / (60*60*24));
```